# True random number generator using VHDL

Tags: random, numbers

I'm asked to design a true random generator using VHDL.With lot of struggle I could only design a PRNGs not TRNG. Is it possible to generate number perfectly random??? Please suggest me in this. I'm really clueless!

Comment: no, a number will NEVER be truly random, its just a question of how close we can get.

Answer (score 2):

There is NO such thing as a "true" random number generator.  This is one of my favorite pseudo-random generators however, and would be fun to implement in VHDL.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift

Also, see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#.22True.22_random_numbers_vs._pseudorandom_numbers

The only thing that I can think of to get you "better" randomness would be to do something like write a file and then read a file.  The scheduler on the host PC *might* have enough entropy associated with it to cause some variance in the time it takes for these operations and you could use that time as a key to seed your algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking about VHDL, you want to design special-purpose hardware. Now if you operate hardware in a way which should never be done for digital logic, you might get some kind of "true" random behavior.
If, e.g., you design a circuit with a D-type flip-flop that is clocked when its data input changes its level, the output becomes metastable, i.e. is some time undefined (between 0 and 1), before it becomes stable as 0 or 1 again. How long this takes, depends among others on the electric noise, e.g. is random. I could imagine that you can use such effects to make a random generator.

Comment: thank u all for ur replies.I'm thinking to use a register holding different values and take it each time the repetition starts. the idea is to provide different seed values so I can get random values. Since I'm new to VHDL coding, Im not sure if this works but just a try from my side if I can do like this. Any suggestions are welcomed on this.

Comment: OK, but your question was about "true" random numbers, which cannot be generated in principle by standard digital logic, as the others have already pointed out. What I suggested CAN generate true random values (of course with a certain distribution), using commodity digital logic, although it is abused a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the claims of most of the other answers, there **are** several **T**RNG designs for FPGAs mostly based on ring oscillators or self-timed rings, see e.g.

[B. Yang, "True Random Number Generators for FPGAs," PhD thesis, KU Leuven, N. Mentens, and I. Verbauwhede (promotors),  2018.](https://www.esat.kuleuven.be/cosic/publications/thesis-307.pdf)

and

[VHDL TRNG designs](https://labh-curien.univ-st-etienne.fr/cryptarchi/HECTOR_TRNG_designs/index.html)

Comment: You're citing a paper from 2018 as a reason why answers given in 2013 were incorrect. Please edit the tone of your answer. Furthermore just because that paper calls the various entropy sources that can be implemented electronically "TRNGs" does not mean that a real implementation devoid of ideal circumstances actually would be a TRNG. Anything electronic is suspectible to real world external influences and cannot be guaranteed as a TRNG (at least for absolute definitions of "True") but is probably still a pretty good PRNG.

Comment: Also if I were being especially picky, I'd point out that their chosen entropy source, a ring oscillator implemented on the FPGA, relies on features (fast carry chain elements) found on a lot of FPGAs these days. These can be accessed from VHDL, but aren't implemented in VHDL. The original poster may well have meant to ask, can a TRNG be implemented on an FPGA, but actually asked whether one can be implemented in VHDL. This paper still doesn't make the answer "yes".

Answer (score 0):

thank u all for ur replies.I'm thinking to use a register holding different values and take it each time the repetition starts. the idea is to provide different seed values so I can get random values. Since I'm new to VHDL coding, Im not sure if this works but just a try from my side if I can do like this. Any suggestions are welcomed on this.

Answer (score -1):

You're not going to get a true random number generator out of an FPGA / VHDL. The best you can hope for is a h/w PRNG that's readable from some register somewhere.

You might choose to implement one of the PRNG algorithms out there. You're then going to have to trust the algorithm designer and then trust which ever VHDL implementation you go with (your own or one you acquire off someone else). You might start by looking at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pseudorandom_number_generators#Cryptographic_algorithms